# Animated routes switching with data fetching, Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am using Vue, Vuex, and Vue-router. There is a list of router-link elements. When clicked, the component in the router-view area should switch with animation and the route url should change. In other words, the old component should disappear completely, then there is a request to the server for data for the new component, and then the new component appears smoothly. But this does not happen. After clicking on the router-link, the data for the new route is loaded quickly and the NEW component disappears smoothly, then it appears smoothly.

What am I doing wrong that a new component disappears? I make a request for data in the beforeRouteEnter and beforeRouteUpdate hooks.

LessonsList.vue

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <router-link 
          v-for="(lesson,index) in lessons"
          v-bind:key="index"
          :to="{
             name: 'lesson',
             params: {
               id: index+1
             }
           }"
           tag="li"
      >
        <h2>№{{index+1}}</h2>
      </router-link>
    </ul>
    <transition name="slide" mode="out-in" appear>
            <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
    </transition>
  </section>
```

Lesson.vue

```js
import {store} from '../../vuex/store'
    
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  let sendData = {};
  sendData.lessonNumber = Number(to.params.id);
  sendData.userId = store.getters['login/userId'];
  store.dispatch('lesson/changeCurrentLesson', sendData).then(()=> next());
  //dispatch action to vuex for data fetching
},
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next){
  let sendData = {};
  sendData.lessonNumber = Number(to.params.id);
  sendData.userId = store.getters['login/userId'];
  store.dispatch('lesson/changeCurrentLesson', sendData).then(()=> next());
}
```

Comment: This is the exact problem I am having.  It appears that that "slide" type transitions do not do well with data-fetching routes.  I want to slide out the old component/data, start data fetch (showing nothing) and slide in new component/data.  But there's no way to sync that sequence with the transition.

Answer (score 0):

> After clicking on the router-link, the data for the new route is loaded quickly and the NEW component disappears smoothly, then it appears smoothly.

I guess this happens because you are using a single state let's call `currentLesson` when you navigate to the new route (same route different params) then `beforeRouteUpdate` will trigger on old component then update `currentLesson` so you will see it looks like the new component disappears. Then the real new component appears with the same `currentLesson`.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-clarke-8yeon)

So you can solve this problem by use the lesson object with its own key or number. Or instead of using `beforeRouteEnter` and `beforeRouteUpdate` hooks, you can use `created` or `mounted` hooks which I think it's better if you need to show some contents before the API loaded.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-cache-otohk)

Comment: That's a helpful solution but I think the OP wants the slide transition.